# How to save in DB multiple drop-down values?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

The issue that I am facing at getting multiple values according to dropdowns selection, it should work like this:

A user selects the first value (quantity) and then the second value which is the fruit. It should display the values selected and finally the user press the button to save all of the selected values in the database.

Here's my code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="lstQuota">
            <asp:ListItem Text="100 units" Value="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="50 Units" Value="2" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="10 Units" Value="3" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstFruits" CssClass="DropdownList1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Mango" Value="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value="2" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Banana" Value="3" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Guava" Value="4" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Orange" Value="5" />
        </asp:ListBox>
    </div>

    <asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[id*=lstFruits]').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });

        $('.DropdownList1').change(function () {
            alert("Handler for .change() called.");
            var mySelection = $("#<%= lstQuota.ClientID %>").val();
            alert(mySelection);
        });
    });
</script>
```

C# CODE:

```
    protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string message = "";
       foreach (ListItem item in lstFruits.Items)
       {
         if (item.Selected)
         {
          message += item.Text + " " + item.Value + "\\n";
         }
       }
      ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
   }
```

It should display the information selected as:

100 Units - Mango

50 Units - Orange

100 Units Apple

In the code behind, it should save every one of them as new rows.

Can somebody help me out with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us your code behind. So we can get the bigger picture

Comment: There it is, it says **protected void Unnamed_Click** however the main structure is basically the same I have in the button it's just the value of the merge of both selects. Not sure if I explained well

Comment: ohk so you want the jquery to alert the values to the user, as sort of confirmation and then the user clicks save to the database.?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to save it to your values in 'lstFruits' table. but it would be nice if we could see your table structure

Comment: Yes, that's right, basically, the users will see their selection and once they are ready, they hit the button save and it should capture the value of the first and second dropdown and save all the rows, the DB part is not a problem.

Comment: The structure of the table is simple, it's just Id and Fruit, int and varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found by myself, the way is very simple.

There is an asp.net control named "ListBox" which will be populated once the **onselectedindexchanged** method is running, but this needs to be encapsulated under an **UpdatePanel** control. Here is a good reference about the UpdatePanel [UpdatePanel Control in ASP.Net.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f50501/use-updatepanel-control-in-Asp-Net/)
 Then just create a simple string variable which captures the value from the 1st dropdown and the 2nd dropdown button, then create a new ListItem [ListItems and ListBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.items?view=netframework-4.7.2) and finally itinerates the listBox items.